# How to retreive all of the data of a specific pushed ID Child from Firebase or, From a infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get all the stored data from the nodes generated by Push
This is my structure:

[image: ph]

All my nodes give data to various infoWindows
like these:

[image]

Each infoWindow contains data specific to several nodes, what I need is to obtain that data from each of those infoWindows or specific nodes

I need these specific data to put them in another activity, either by getting the data from the node or from the infoWindow
How do I do it?

This is the code that gives the data to the infoWindow:

```
   FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().orderByKey().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        latitud = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getLatitud();
                        longitud = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getLongitud();

                        titulo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getTitulo();
                        costo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getCosto();
                        mes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getMes();
                        numeroDia = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getDia();
                        organizadoPor = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getOrganizadoPor();
                        descripcion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getDescripicion();
                        hora = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getHora();
                        minutos = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getMinutos();




                        BitmapDescriptor bm = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.m5);
                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
                        mMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title(titulo).snippet(costo).icon(bm);
                        mp.add(mMap.addMarker(mMarker));
   }
```

I try with this But it only gives me the data of the last infoWindow:

```
  Post mPost = new Post();
  Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("abc", mPost):
```

the OtherActivity:

```
  Intent Intent = getIntent();
   mPost = (Post) intent.getSerializableExtra("abc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code to be like below.but you need to set data into your `post` object. you will attach your post data into your marker using mMarker.setTag(post); for more information have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker-data) link.

```
   FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().orderByKey().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        latitud = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getLatitud();
                        longitud = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getLongitud();

                        titulo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getTitulo();
                        costo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getCosto();
                        mes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getMes();
                        numeroDia = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getDia();
                        organizadoPor = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getOrganizadoPor();
                        descripcion = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getDescripicion();
                        hora = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getHora();
                        minutos = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class).getMinutos();

                        Post post = new Post();
                        // add all your data to post object e.g post.setLatitud(latitud);

                        BitmapDescriptor bm = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.m5);
                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
                        mMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title(titulo).snippet(costo).icon(bm);
                        mp.add(mMap.addMarker(mMarker));

                        // Associate your post data with the marker
                        mMarker.setTag(post);


                        }
                });
```

use this method to detect marker clicks

```
private void onMarkerClicked() {
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // get the data from clicked marker and attach it with the intent 
            bundle.putSerializable("post", (Post) marker.getTag());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

in your OtherActivity use this to get the data .

```
  Post mPost = (Post) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("post");
```

your Post model could be like this.

```
public class Post implements Serializable{

   private String latitud,longitud,costo,titulo,mes,numeroDia,organizadoPor,descripcion,hora,minutos ;


public String getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(String latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

public String getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(String longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

public String getCosto() {
    return costo;
}

public void setCosto(String costo) {
    this.costo = costo;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getMes() {
    return mes;
}

public void setMes(String mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public String getNumeroDia() {
    return numeroDia;
}

public void setNumeroDia(String numeroDia) {
    this.numeroDia = numeroDia;
}

public String getOrganizadoPor() {
    return organizadoPor;
}

public void setOrganizadoPor(String organizadoPor) {
    this.organizadoPor = organizadoPor;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public String getMinutos() {
    return minutos;
}

public void setMinutos(String minutos) {
    this.minutos = minutos;
}
 }
```

Comment: Doesnt works, this give me the ultimate Post data object i need the specific data

Comment: how do you want to filter your nodes ?

Comment: I need to click on a marker that contains data from firebase, that data of that specific marker, is transferred to another activity but I do not know how to do it

Comment: aha , i finally understood your problem . i will edit my answer for you :)

Comment: Still not working, click to give me the data of the last mPost "Tag",
A marker has title "A"
And the other marker has title "B"

When I click on marker "A" in the activity, it gives me the title "B" the last tag
And I need the "Specific Title"